# Select text from element and use it in script (AddThis)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="file-section">
    <div class="middle">
        <p class="description">
            Lorem ipsum...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var addthis_share = {
    description: $('#file-section .middle p.description').text(),
    templates: { twitter: 'Default Message' }
}
```

I want to use all the text that's in the p.description paragraph tag as the description (in the jQuery script). I tried it with the jQuery code above, but I can't get it to work. Because it doesn't return any text. I tested to see if it worked with alert(), but it alerted no text, so I assume it doesn't work.

By the way, the piece of script is to set-up the AddThis Social Share information.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML code as well?  We might be able to present you with a different solution.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, chec your html code or paste here

Comment: It's in general no good statement to say "it doesn't work". Please specify your problem further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
alert($('#file-section').find('p.description').html());
```

Comment: I have tried it in my computer and works fine. The result of the alert is.... "Lorem ipsum..."